# Draw image in xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

I was able to draw a cross button like this with a lot of code and effort:

[image]

This little cross took me all of this code:

```
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#bbb" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1px"
            android:color="@color/black" />
        <padding android:bottom="2dp"
            android:left="2dp"
            android:right="2dp"
            android:top="2dp"
            />
        <size
            android:width="18dp"
            android:height="18dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:toDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%">

        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/black" />
            <size
                android:width="10dp"
                android:height="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>

<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="135"
        android:toDegrees="135"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%">


        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/black" />
            <size
                android:width="10dp"
                android:height="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

I would like to ask someone experienced how to draw the following picture more easily:

[image]

Comment: Well, I have been strugling for more than 2 hours with this simple image and no luck. I didn't manage to do it. Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Drawing your own buttons is fun, but if you would like to save yourself some time and effort, you should [check out this site](http://www.icons4android.com/), which provides over 1500 free icon resources for your Android application in different resolutions.

Additionally, you can download the [official android icon pack](https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html) which provides more than enough standard icons in mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi.

Lastly, if none of these icons would suit you, you can create your own icons from your own image resources using the [Launcher Icon Generator](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html).

In your example, you probably would like an icon looking like this (taken from the official android icon pack, see above link):

[image]

Which is easily added in your `drawable` folder and then set as a background to an `ImageView` element:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/your_icon" />
```

Comment: Nice one for the icons, thx. Anyways, I prefer xml. The apk is smaller and I would like to create a selector too. Furthermore, I really don't like messing up with mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, etc. ...

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_expand_up"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_up_24dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a lot of code at all...in my humble opinion i think that you took the right approach. If you do not have the image and need to build it manually, declaring it in xml let you avoid to write code and keep things organized.